# How to remove the .tmp file created by TempFileCollection in C#?

Tags: c#

How to remove the .tmp file created by TempFileCollection in C#?

```
TempInputCollection = new TempFileCollection("TempDirectoryPathHere", true);
string TempFile = TempInputCollection.AddExtension("xml");
```

The problem is, when I decide to keep the temporary files, there is not only an .xml
file, but only a .tmp file which I did not create. How do I get rid of that .tmp file
and just keep my .xml file when I decide to keep temporary files as here?

Comment: you want to delete the temp file programmatically?

Comment: @HackerMan yep of course. I am not sure why it was automatically created anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to using directives  `using System.IO;`

```
 File.Delete("File path");
```

try this code...